# Laravel - writing exception for schedule event in model listener

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-events

I've a Model `Product` that fires `retrieved` event `ProductRetrieved` and a listener `CheckProductValidity` that throws an exception depending on the API path (if-else condition).

Also, I've a update query that I have implemented in `Console\Kernal.php` that runs everyday at 00:00 Hours.

**Problem:** `CheckProductValidity` throws an exception for scheduled tasks. How do I make an exception in listener to allow retrieval of model `Product` data when it is done by scheduler.

**Possible solution:** Use `unsetEventDispatcher` and `setEventDispatcher` but at times this update query may take more than usual time. Also, cron also sends notifications and processes jobs (all depending on `Product`) so that might cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution but this is how I fixed it.

```
// fix to catch if artisan schedule:run has intiated this check;
$parameters = app('request')->server->get('argv');

$allowed_commands = ['schedule:run', 'migrate:refresh', 'db:seed', 'queue:work'];

if ($parameters[0]==='artisan'
    && in_array($parameters[1], $allowed_commands))
    return true;
```

In the listener I added this code which would check if the request was a result of `artisan` command or a `route`.